# unable to print a greek character in pdf using php script & fpdf

Tags: php, character-encoding, pdf-generation, fpdf

while trying to print a greek character `'φ'` I get the following character printed on the pdf `'Ï†'`

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried? Are you sure you use the proper encoding? Are you sure the font you want to use contains this character?

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, I was able to resolve the problem myself, I'll post it here, below, soon ... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use the TFPDF extension of the FPDF project. TFPDF uses multi-byte string functions and writes its output with a UTF-8 encoding, while FPDF does not.

See:

http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

Comment: finally I could do it with the help of fpdf itself ... :)

Comment: This is far the best answer.. all you need to do is download on the bottom in the link `http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php` the zip .. and you are ready to go

Answer (score 6):

I will leave this here for the next ones.

[FPDF has its own guide](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm) for importing new fonts for specific encodings.
The steps are:

1. Go to http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/ and upload the .ttf or .otf file of your font (make sure font is supporting greek characters like Courier New).
2. For the encoding option select ISO-8859-7 (preferably) or cp1253 according to the guide.
3. Download the .php and .z files that are created and store them on fpdf/font folder (like the default fonts) of the fpdf package.
4. Import the font at runtime to the pdf file `$pdf->AddFont('Courier New', '', 'Courier New.php');`
5. And use it `$pdf->SetFont('Courier New', '', 20);`
6. You have to convert the string you will print to ISO-8859-7 encoding. This is done with `$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-7', $text);`
7. Then you can finally print the string `$pdf->Write(20,$text);`